# Cannot access subpage url of subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I did a rewrite rule for wildcard subdomain access to allow me to access any countries of my list page as follows:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(.+)\.mydomain\.net$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www\.mydomain\.net$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*)            pages/list.php?country=%1 [L]
```

This is working fine.

Now. I do a rewrite rule to access another page on the domain but i keep getting referred back to the list page.

```
    RewriteRule    ^ad/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$        pages/details.php?alias=$1                                          [NC,L]
```

My end result is to access eg: http://us.mydomain.net/ad/alias but it keeps referring me back to the list page.

UPDATED REWRITE RULES(AS OF 14 MAY)

```
        RewriteEngine on

        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
           Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </IfModule>

        RewriteRule ^cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?category=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(.+)\.ibizportal\.net$
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www\.ibizportal\.net$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*)            pages/list.php?country=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?category=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.mydomain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) pages/list.php?country=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i think my site works better now. I can access the absolute urls but for following mod rewrites, i cannot access their edited urls

Comment: Not getting 404 errors. The pages loads but i can't move out of list page into other pages. I can load it if i type in http://us.mydomain.net/pages/details.php?adid=1

Comment: The above link loads properly and take me to the proper page but when i try going to the same page with a rewritten url http://us.mydomain.net/ad/automotive/3/car-for-sale. It referred me back to the list page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77676/discussion-between-lawrence-and-anubhava).

Comment: You can try the live site at http://gb.ibizportal.net. You can see that the $_GET is getting the right attributes but when i go to http://gb.ibizportal.net/cat/automotive, the category which is supposed to be there, is not shown.

Comment: I thank you for your patience. But its still not working. Check my latest Rewrite rules but its still not working.

Comment: Updated. But no avail. You can try the new rewrite rules and you see that they are referring back to the home page. Same as http://ibizportal.net